# Decidability of predicate calculus with equality only

Tags: logic, algorithms, computability, predicate-logic

I read in some books that propositional calculus is decidable (e.g. with truth tables), and predicate calculus is not decidable (as proved by Church and Turing). Unfortunately, I do not exactly understand the scope of the latter claim. Let me explain what I know about predicate calculus (please correct me if I'm wrong):

In its minimal form, predicate calculus is the pure predicate calculus with equality: its language has a complete set of logical connectives, unlimited supply of individual variables, quantifiers $\forall,\exists$, and a special binary predicate symbol $=$ for equality. It also has usual logical axioms and inference rules, including axioms for equality.

In a more rich form, predicate calculus can additionally have a finite set of individual constants, a finite set of n-ary functional symbols, a finite set of n-ary predicate symbols, and additional axioms for manipulating those symbols (we assume that the axioms are effectively generated, and "being an axiom" is a decidable property of a formula).

Does the undecidability result applies to the minimal form (the pure predicate calculus with equality), or it's a weaker result saying that no decision procedure exist that would handle all general forms of predicate calculus?

Thanks!

Comment: "The validities of monadic predicate calculus with identity are decidable, however. This system is first-order logic restricted to signatures that have no function symbols and whose relation symbols other than equality never take more than one argument." ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decidability_(logic)#Decidability_of_a_logical_system))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for something such as [monadic predicate calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monadic_predicate_calculus).

This is a fragment of the predicate calculus very much alike the "minimal form" you described: in monadic predicate calculus all the relation and function symbols are monadic, that is, there are no n-ary function and relation symbols.

Now, to answer to your question, what is interesting about monadic predicate calculus is that it is **decidable** (Löwenheim 1915), that is, the undecidability result does not apply to it.

Answer (score 2):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Original_proof_of_G%C3%B6del's_completeness_theorem#Extension_to_first-order_predicate_calculus_with_equality), you get decidability even with equality for the pure predicate calculus. Beyond that, you are looking at first-order languages, which have various formalisations, and which are generally not decidable. At least that's my understanding.